# How to calculate or estimate power inverter's peak power

Tags: inverter, solar-energy, ups

What should be fine to consider as peak power output of an inverter when a motor starts for example?
given that:
Capacity (Rated Power): 935VA / 12 V
Solar UPS Overload:110%
Solar UPS Short Circuit 300%

"full" specifications are here:
https://www.microtekdirect.com/solar-pcu-123512v-129.html

Comment: As a general rule, I figure that the peak is about three times the average. So if you figure about 250 W average (fridge + extras) then I'd guess at 750 W peak. This tends to be about right for refrigerators, though I cannot speak to evaporators and ceiling fan motors. But it should be in the ballpark. So I'd probably imagine that your 935 VA unit would be sufficient. Not with lots of margin. But just barely where I'd want it if saving money.

Comment: @periblepsis I meant the peak power this particular inverter is capable of outputing and not for the appliances. Edited the question deleting that part

Comment: The peak power over 1 \$\mu s\$ will be very much bigger than the peak power over 1 ms or 1 second.

Comment: @Andyaka  5 to 15 seconds